# Points on a p-adic circle

Tags: geometry, field-theory

I was wondering if anybody could point me to any interesting geometry (if there is any) that the p-adic circle has. Specifically, let $G_p=\{ (x,y)\in (\mathbb{Q}_p)^2 \,:\, x^2+y^2=1\}.$ Does $G_p$ have any type of group structure?Since $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is non-archimedean, I'm not sure in what contexts anybody studies this, but here goes nothing. I'm wondering if one could potentially exhibit points on $G_p$ whose mutual distances are rational and with the additional property that these points are dense. This is similar to the classical geometric problem.

Comment: If $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ , then $G_p$ can be naturally embedded in $\Bbb{Q}_p[i]$, which is the $p$-adic version of $\Bbb{C}$ (i.e. $\Bbb{Q}_p[i] = \Bbb{Q}_p[X]/(X^2+1)$). In here, $G_p$ is a multiplicative subgroup of $\Bbb{Q}_p[i]$, the $p$-adic circle group.

Comment: Why is the restriction that $p\equiv 3 \mbox{ mod }4$ necessary? Can you give me a reference to read? Thanks!

Comment: Actually this is not necessary; this condition is equivalent to the condition that $X^2+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}_p[X]$, so that $\Bbb{Q}_p[X] / (X^2+1)$ is a field. Anyway, $G_p$ is always a group with the usual multiplication $$(a,b) \cdot (c,d) = (ad-bc , ac+bd)$$ with $(1,0)$ as identity and $(a,b)^{-1}=(a,-b)$.

Comment: So is there a notion of distance between elements of $\mathbb{Q}_p[i]$ ? Could it be the same as in $\mathbb{C}$ : $$|x-y|=\sqrt{(x-y)(\bar{x}-\bar{y})} ?$$